# Force IPv4 over IPv6 only for certain addresses

Tags: debian, networking, ipv6, ipv4

I'm currently running Debian 8 and I'm trying to force applications like Google Chrome to use IPv4 over IPv6 only for certain sites.
My ISP natively offers IPv6 and it's amazing on all websites that support it except for Facebook.
If I browse Facebook when I'm using an IPv6 connection the site is really slow and if I completely disable IPv6 everything start working again.
So my aim is to automatically force an IPv4 connection only for Facebook and to keep it default for every other IP/domain.
I tried to look online and the only method that I've found is to edit gai.conf but I'm unable to make it work. It seems that the file is being ignored. This is what I've added:

---

`label 0:0:0:0:0:FFFF:ADFC:7806/128 5
precedence 0:0:0:0:0:FFFF:ADFC:7806/128 100`

---

I converted the original IPv4 (173.252.120.6) to an IPv6 address and used that in the configuration file. Except for the two lines that I've added the rest of the file was commented. Can someone help me?

Comment: I think that you're on the right path by shifting the question to forcing IPv4 for certain **IP addresses** instead of for certain **domains**, and editing `gai.conf` is indeed the right way to do that. But you will certainly want to be configuring Facebook's IPv6 addresses into that file. I'm at a loss trying to figure out why you are using IPv6-mapped-IPv4 addresses in there (addresses of the form ::ffff:xxxx:yyyy) as I'm not sure what such addresses even mean in this context.

Comment: @Celada Doing it based on IP address does mean that the choice between the addresses can only be done after DNS resolution. That might cost an extra roundtrip - unless the A and AAAA records are looked up in parallel.

Comment: @kasperd I've also just realised that this method is not efficient because Facebook has numerous hostnames and IP addresses, as part of their CDN network, and I just can't insert all of them. So I don't think that the gai.conf way is the right one.

Comment: @LookedPath It is indeed tricky to produce a full list of all the domains and IP addresses which they use. But what you really want is not necessarily a full list, but just a list of those which are slow when accessed over IPv6. It sounds very plausible that access to the host being slow over IPv6 is more likely to be correlated with the IP address than with the hostname. That's one good argument for going for the IP addresses, and for a start you could just add IP address one range at a time as you notice slow connections.

Comment: @LookedPath Chrome is supposed to automatically detect whether IPv4 or IPv6 is faster and use that. There is a few caveats though. For a start only the time to complete a handshake will be considered, and sometimes the one completing a handshake fastest isn't the fastest for the rest of the connection. If a browser tries to remember which protocol gave fastest responses on previous connections, it is tricky to figure out what exactly is the useful scope of those measurements.

Comment: @kasperd I'm going insane because to completely load any Facebook page it takes up to 20 seconds.Analyzing load times with Chrome I noticed that it takes ages to download key contents but the response time is normal. I can't disable IPv6 system-wide because with every Google service it's the opposite, I can only use them on IPv6.Since it's hard to find someone of my ISP support that knows what I'm talking about I need a workaround until they solve their problems.The only thing that I can think about is to setup a DNS server in my home but before doing that I would prefer a simpler solution.

Comment: Can you check to see if you're blocking PMTU? We're looking at this internally, but this sounds like a mtu issue

Comment: @PaulSaab I searched online how to check that, because I didn't know, and I ran some pings with different sizes and it behaves strangely. Here is the output [link](http://pastebin.com/fveNzPn3)

Comment: @PaulSaab I'm sorry, I was wrong as everything is working as expected. I just did the math wrong. In fact ping6 gets an MTU of 1480 and the biggest fragment size that I can use is 1432.

Comment: If you do have a PMTU issue the most efficient workaround in my experience is to have the gateway reduce the MSS to 1220 on every SYN packet which originally had MSS higher than that. And it doesn't hurt to do this for both IPv4 and IPv6.

Comment: @kasperd From the tests that I ran I saw that PMTU is working fine as the values of MTU that it's finding are correctly working. I even tried decreasing the MTU size in my devices but the problem was still there.  My problem is that I can't change those advanced settings in my VDSL gateway because it has very basic configurations since it's from my ISP. They closed it and I can't change it because telephony is VOIP and they don't want users to find the parameters.

Comment: This suggests your ISP is tunnelling IPv6 somewhere in their network, rather than running native dual stack (the normal best practice). If you have a home router of your own, lowering the MTU on its WAN interface should help.

Comment: @MichaelHampton in fact my ISP is using a tunnel to provide IPv6. Now I'm using the routing capabilities of the gateway and my Netgear R7000 is in AP mode and for my LAN architecture it has to stay that way. So the only choice is to decrease the MTU on each client right? If yes, is there a way for choosing the right size without testing all of them? Thanks

Comment: You can drop the MTU to the minimum 1280, which should always work, and you really won't lose much throughput. Otherwise it's experimentation.

Comment: @MichaelHampton thanks for the suggestion. I'll try that and I'll let you know if it works.